# HTML map check for overlaps

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

I have several `<area>`s on my map, and I would like to see if any of them overlap, and if so, where. So far, the simplest way I could think of is give each one a thin border; however, `<area style="border:1px solid blue">` doesn't seem to be working. How would I do that (I'd also be happy to know of any better ways check for overlaps)? JavaScript and jQuery allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this jquery plugin: https://github.com/kemayo/maphilight/

Docs: http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/